# Should your Resume refer to the company's current name, or name at the time?

Tags: resume

I have had several previous jobs where the faculty names have changed, or the company has since rebranded. Seeing the old company names looks dated to my eyes, is it common practice to update the company names? Or is that misinformation?

Space is at a premium on my CV, and mentioning both names would look moderately clumsy, so can someone confirm that this is common practice, or whether it is a a bit of a no-no?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both.  Up to you if you want to write `Old Name (now known as New Name)`, or `New Name (formerly Old Name)`.  Both convey the same information, and there's no real reason to prefer one over the other.

You need to provide both; because HR will need the new name to find the company via Google, but a background check will probably have the name of the company when you worked for it.

Comment: And also, consider mergers - when HP and Compaq merged, all those ex-Compaq engineers didn't suddenly become ex-HP engineers